# When and how to use Html5DateRenderingMode

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5.2

I understand that Html5DateRenderingMode is used for displaying date/time related values and can be set as -

```
@{ Html.Html5DateRenderingMode = Html5DateRenderingMode.Rfc3339; }
@{ Html.Html5DateRenderingMode = Html5DateRenderingMode.CurrentCulture; }
```

Which I have tried declaring in View(.cshtml). When used with EditorFor as -

```
@Html.EditorFor(emp => emp.StartDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

It displays date according to the declared RenderingMode.

Questions -
- Do we always set the date rendering mode in View(.cshtml) or can we declare it in ViewModel as well. If yes, how?
- What could be the practical usage of setting Html5DateRenderingMode? 
(Thinking if same can be achieved using ApplyFormatInEditMode and DataFormatString annotations)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documentation on this particular property is annoyingly sparse. Just about the best description of its purpose is found in the source:

```
// Copyright (c) Microsoft Open Technologies, Inc. All rights reserved. See License.txt in the project root for license information.

namespace System.Web.Mvc
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Controls the value-rendering method For HTML5 input elements of types such as date, time, datetime and datetime-local.
    /// </summary>
    public enum Html5DateRenderingMode
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Render date and time values according to the current culture's ToString behavior.
        /// </summary>
        CurrentCulture = 0,

        /// <summary>
        /// Render date and time values as Rfc3339 compliant strings to support HTML5 date and time types of input elements.
        /// </summary>
        Rfc3339,
    }
}
```

When dealing with the date/time related HTML5 input types, the `value` of the input *must* be set to ISO, or "Rfc339" format, or the built-in browser controls won't be able to interpret the date/time properly. This only applies when using a modern browser that supports these types and presents a calendar/time control to allow you pick or otherwise enter the datetime info in a structured way.

Rather than two separate choices, this enum is really just an on/off switch, and most likely exists to permit a bit of flexibility depending on your target audience. If you actually *want* just a standard text input or you're focused only on desktop, where browser support is sadly still pitiful to this day, then you may want the input value to be more "friendly" to the user by being their current culture, i.e. `08/12/2015` vs `2015-08-12`. However, if you want to rely on what browser controls exist, if any, using polyfills where necessary, or are focused on mobile, where support is universal, then you want the values output in proper ISO format.

Honestly, though, I've never fooled with this setting before and have never really had a need to.

As far as the `DataFormatString` attribute and its `ApplyFormatInEditMode` parameter goes, yes, you can pretty much achieve the same thing using that. It's a little more loose in that you can use *any* format, but if you apply ISO format in edit mode, then you're doing the same as this setting would when set to `Html5DateRenderingMode.Rfc3339`.